# Why is logging setup in CreateHostBuilder and not in ConfigureServices?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

Context: Simple out-of-the-box blazor 3.1 SERVER SIDE example - adding logging (just trying to get stuff to the debug conolse in VS2019 in components).

I leave ConfigureServices as is, and have found SO examples that logging is setup in program.cs(!)
This works:

```
    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureLogging(
                logging =>
                {
                    logging.ClearProviders();
                    logging.AddConsole();
                })
```

ect.

In my components, everything is resolved fine with

```
[Inject] public ILogger<Foo> Logger { get; set; }
```

But why not in ConfigureServices, where rest of stuff, that should be DI'ed, is setup ???

1. Is there a "under the hood" DI going on? (a little like what was
   going on in .Net frameework w/ webapi)?
2. Can it be moved to ConfigureServices with *excact* same result (or
   at all )?

Answer (score 1):

In ASP.NET core 2.x you could partially configure your dependency injection container in Program.cs, and inject the configured classes into Startup.cs. So the `ConfigureLogging()` method calls `ConfigureServices()` on the `IWebHostBuilder` instance, and configures some settings. As these services are configured in the DI container before `Startup` is instantiated, they can be injected into the `Startup` constructor:

```
public Startup(
  IConfiguration configuration, 
  ILogger<Startup> logger) // Inject pre-configured service
{
}
```

[More](https://andrewlock.net/avoiding-startup-service-injection-in-asp-net-core-3/)

**But this approach is no longer supported in ASP.NET Core 3.0!** The problem is that it requires building the dependency injection container [twice](https://andrewlock.net/avoiding-startup-service-injection-in-asp-net-core-3/#two-singletons-).

> 1. Is there a "under the hood" DI going on? (a little like what was going
>      on in .Net frameework w/ webapi)?

The `ConfigureLogging` just call `ConfigureServices` without building of service provider

```
public static IWebHostBuilder ConfigureLogging(this IWebHostBuilder hostBuilder, Action<WebHostBuilderContext, ILoggingBuilder> configureLogging)
{
     return hostBuilder.ConfigureServices((context, collection) => collection.AddLogging(builder => configureLogging(context, builder)));
}
```

> 2. Can it be moved to ConfigureServices with excact same result (or at all )?

yes, you can move it to `ConfigureServices` and the result will be the same

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddLogging(builder =>
    {
        builder.ClearProviders();
        builder.AddConsole();
    });
}
```

So, where to add logging configuration is up to you. Logging is infrastructure and can be added as a configuration of host to Program.cs. Your business classes should be added to DI in Startup.

Comment: You can call `AddLogging` inside `ConfigureServices` but what use is that?  It still doesn't give your code within `ConfigureServices` access to an `ILogger`.

Comment: @Jez as I see the question is not about how to access ILogger in ConfigureServices